# MVC3 Validation on view remains invalid due to DropDownList

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I've had to add a manual DropDownList within my Create View giving the user 2 options of 'input '.

Now the validation doesn't work when I come to save the information even though my code is now:

```
 <div class="editor-field">
            <select name="type" id="type">
            <option value></option>
            <option value="1" id="apple">Apple</option>
            <option value="2" id="banana">Banana</option>
            </select>
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="type" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```

How do I get the built in validation back on the 'Type'field. I have this as 'Required' within the model class.

Answer (score 0):

your drop-down Name and ID should be a property of your model.

```
 <select name="type" id="type">
```

include type as a Property in your Model and make it required.

```
public class myModel{
    [Required]
    public string type{get; set;}
}
```

being type a c# keyword I would suggest you to use something else as your property name for example **"FruitDD"**

Comment: You can always escape the keyword with `@`. E.g. `public string @type { get; set; }`

Comment: that is true, but it would be much better not to use reserved keywords unless it is very much required. in the above situation i felt he could use a different property.

Comment: I agree, avoiding the use of keywords as property names is important in design because they make code harder to interpret and cause workarounds such as `@`.